# Flying USA to UK via Canada with Spanish passport. Do I need to apply for a visa?

Tags: visas, transit, canada, spanish-citizens

I'm flying from Los Angeles to London with one stop at Vancouver International Airport to change planes in the same flight. I have both current Spanish passport and ESTA.

Do I need to apply for visa to connect through Canada without exiting the airport?

Comment: Another related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22394/travelling-from-us-to-sri-lanka-do-i-need-transit-visa-for-canada?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Spanish citizens do not require a visa to enter Canada for short-term stays, including transit.  The only requirement is that you have proof of onward travel (which obviously you will), and sufficient funds for your stay in Canada (which would be $0 given you are only in transit).

Comment: This answer was correct at the time of posting, but nowadays you also need an ETA.